# How do I create unique updating list if criteria is met in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, list, if-statement, unique

I want to copy a certain range of columns to another worksheet if certain criteria are met.

**IF** D36:D160 is "Fælles" or "Lagt ud"
**THEN** columns A:H in this region should be copied to another worksheet in the workbook in the same region.

However, it has to go in the first blank space and be the unique values.

As the list is updating it has to copy to the other without copying the same data.

Bear in mind that I am a carpenter making a budget for me and my partner in my spare time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
A = Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 34 To A

    If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Fælles" Then

        Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    ElseIf Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then

        Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Stig Jan").Activate

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
I have successfully copied both the criteria "Fælles" and "Lagt ud" to the other worksheet. Now I just need a code which copies unique values to the other list which are not there from before. So I can keep updating the list by hitting the command button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
index(range;row;column)
```

or

```
Vlookup()
```

easier

Comment: Thank you Mahrous! I have just about zero experience and knowledge of this and have just scrambled myself through this code by looking at different examples. Could you please use your examples in context? :)